# Returning corresponding column using awk

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, awk

I am writing a small bash script that would search for a string, decode it and then echo out the result. However, the logfile which I am parsing is in the following structure:

```
<filename/path to file> <signature>
```

So far I am extracting only the signatures, take them through a regular expression and then decode whatever has matched the regex. I would also like to output the file which corresponds to the signature I grepped like so:

```
<filename/path to file> <decoded signature>
<filename/path to file> <decoded signature>
```

And what my current output is like is the following:

```
<decoded signature>
<decoded signature>
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p $'\e[1;33mLogfile\e[0m: ' sigs

parse=$( awk 'NF > 1 {print $2}' "$sigs")

Array=($( grep -ra "$parse" /var/lib/clamav | grep -oP "(?<=^|[*{};])[A-Fa-f0-9]+(?=$|[*;{}])"))

 for hex in "${Array[@]}"; do 
      converted="$(xxd -r -p <<< "$hex")"
      echo -e "\e[92m$converted \e[0m"
 done
```

Would it be a good idea if I store all the contents of the logfile in an array where the element would be the filename and the key its decoded signature?

## **UPDATE**

**Log file (logfile.txt)** -> what I'm parsing;

```
/public_html/n0g6v/content/execution-after-redirect.html: {LDB}VT-malware33.UNOFFICIAL FOUND
/public_html/n0g6v/paypal-gateway.html: Html.Exploit.CVE.2015_6073
```

**/var/lib/clamav/daily.cld** -> where I'm getting the signatures' HEX values for decoding;

```
Html.Exploit.CVE_2015_6073;Engine:51-255,Target:3;0&1;696e7365727461646a6163656e7468746d6c;6164646576656e746c697374656e6572{-30}646f6d6e6f646572656d6f766564*737761706e6f6465
```

=========================================================

## Sample input:

```
logfile.txt
```

## Output:

```
/public_html/n0g6v/content/execution-after-redirect.html:
/public_html/n0g6v/paypal-gateway.html:
insertadjacenthtml
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/public_html/n0g6v/content/execution-after-redirect.html:
/public_html/n0g6v/paypal-gateway.html:
addeventlistener
```

=========================================================

How I would like it to be:

## Sample input:

```
logfile.txt
```

## Output:

```
/public_html/n0g6v/content/execution-after-redirect.html:
<No match found for this signature>
/public_html/n0g6v/paypal-gateway.html:
insertadjacenthtml
addeventlistener
```

Comment: Show some concrete (either real or realistically fake) input and the desired output. I bet you'll get one or a few answers that do the whole thing easily with just awk.

Comment: Thanks. Made an update with the sample input/output and expected ones.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

if your look up file is not huge, load into an `awk` array and search field 2 from your log file, if found call your conversion script and print results.

for example, this code should be clear..

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{split($0,a,";"); 
               lookup[a[1]]=$0; next} 
              {inlookup=$2 in lookup; 
               print $2; 
               if(!inlookup) 
                 {print "<No match found for this signature>";
                  next}
               } 
               {split(lookup[$2],h,";"); 
                for(i=4;i<=length(h);i++) 
                   {cmd="wc -c <<< \"" h[i] "\""; 
                    cmd | getline d; print d, h[i]}}' daily logfile

{LDB}VT-malware33.UNOFFICIAL
<No match found for this signature>
Html.Exploit.CVE_2015_6073
37 696e7365727461646a6163656e7468746d6c
83 6164646576656e746c697374656e6572{-30}646f6d6e6f646572656d6f766564*737761706e6f6465
```

here instead of decoding I did `wc -c` but the same principle applies.  Note also that the given two files the values don't match due to `.` and `_` mismatch, need to fix the typo for this to work.

Comment: I am sorry but could you please elaborate? I tried to run that through the console and renaming the files with their full paths but was unable to execute it properly. Got: `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=/var/lib/clamav/daily.cld FNR=1793447) fatal: dupnode: r->stptr: can't allocate 61 bytes of memory (Cannot allocate memory)` . My main point is automating this procedure and I think a single script could do just fine instead of including/calling external ones that handle different parts of it.

Comment: "if your look up file is not huge" doesn't apply then.  It won't fit in your memory so you need another approach.  This awk script could have replaced your bash script altogether but alas...

Comment: Well I simply need to echo out the file name for the corresponding signature so I don't see why I would have to replace the entire script with an entirely different approach.

Comment: No, there is no need obviously, for most cases it would speed up (under the condition that the file fits in memory), also most people like the expressive power of `awk` for text processing compared to bash scripts.